# Compiler isn't recognizing overloaded constructor C++

Tags: c++, constructor, constructor-overloading

I'm trying to create a symbol table for a basic compiler. I have 2 constructors in my Symbol class-one that takes 4 parameters, and one that takes 5.
I have a simple main function in that tries to create a Symbol object, taking in 4 parameters, and then another one with 5 parameters. The compiler complains about the Symbol b with 5 parameters:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘Symbol::Symbol(std::string&, std::string&, int, kind, int)’
symbol.h:14: note: candidates are: Symbol::Symbol(const Symbol::string&, const Symbol::string&, int, kind)
 symbol.h:6: note:                 Symbol::Symbol(const Symbol&)
```

I'm not sure why its saying that there is no matching function to call because it is there. Although I'm not sure if the "const Symbol::string&" being different from "std::string&" is causing some issue, or how to fix that if so.

Here is the main:

```
int main(){
    string x="x";
    string y="y";
    Symbol a(x,"int",0,SCALAR);
    Symbol b(y,"char",0,ARRAY,5);

    //operator << is overloaded
    cout << a << endl;
    cout << b << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

symbol.h:

```
#ifndef SYMBOL_H
#define SYMBOL_H
#include "type.h"
#include <string>

class Symbol{
    typedef std::string string;
    string _name;
    Type _type;

public:
    const string& getName() const;
    const Type& getType() const;
    Symbol(const string& name, const string& specifier, int indirection, kind kind); 
    Symbol(const string& name, const string& specifier, int indirection, kind kind, int length); 
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& ostr, const Symbol& symbol);

#endif /*SYMBOL_H*/
```

symbol.cpp

```
#include "symbol.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

/*other member function definitions*/

Symbol::Symbol(const string& name, const string& specifier, int indirection, kind kind)
{
    _name = name;
    Type a(specifier,indirection,kind);
    _type = a;
}

Symbol::Symbol(const string& name, const string& specifier, int indirection, kind kind, int length)
{
    _name = name;

    /*Type is another class that holds the description of the type of the     
     *particular variable, function,etc. declaration
     */

    Type a(specifier,indirection,kind,length);
    _type = a;
}
```

Comment: You compiler thinks there's a trailing `, int` in your call but not in your constructor... suggests this isn't your real code, or you're not doing a fresh build, or something like that.

Comment: ah. yea. It had created a .gch file that I didn't see that must have been outdated. Deleted that and recompiled and it's all good. Thanks @LightnessRacesinOrbit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a precompiled header (.gch) file that must have been outdated. Deleted it and recompiled fine.